# Angular native HTML select with multiple as bound attribute

Tags: angular

I have a `<select>` tag which needs to bind the `multiple` attribute to a value in the component. If I do this:

```
<select [multiple]="multiple" [(ngModel)]="model" id='sel' name='sel'>
<option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option.value">{{option.label}} - {{option.value}}</option>
```

Then I get very quirky behaviour - the page inits with the first item selected, even though the `ngModel` value is set to a different option item. Also, the bound `ngModel` can give an array when it is changed, which you would expect with a `multiple` tag, although I want the tag to be dependent on a boolean value.

Here is a StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bpvmt2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: <select multiple [(ngModel)]="model" id='sel' name='sel'>

Comment: @SaEChowdary that's *always* going to be a multiple. As mentioned in the question, the `multiple` attribute needs to be parameterized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presence of `[multiple]` on `select` tag results in creation of `SelectMultipleControlValueAccessor` for writing multi-select control values and listening to multi-select control changes. This happens irrespective of whether we bind `[multiple]` to true or false value.

[SelectMultipleControlValueAccessor selector](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectMultipleControlValueAccessor#selectors)

So, the value bound to `ngModel` needs to be an array even when `multiple` is set to false. It works, but yes the model would be an array with one element.

Expecting the `model` to switch between an array and non-array type on basis of boolean value bound to `[multiple]`, means that relevant `ControlValueAccessor` directives would need to be dynamically created and associated with same `NgModel` instance.